# Display data from another table for specific logged user in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables "members" and "tbl_users". "members" is for login user and "tbl_users" is for data. When a user submitted a form it will print out from the index but other user also see it even if other user don't submit a form. How do I print out a form data from a specific user?

How do I print out data from specific user using the same database?

```
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','test_user');
define('DBPASS','root');
define('DBNAME','test_db');

try {

    //create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, 
DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger text-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
$user = new User($db);
```

form.php

```
  if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
{
    $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
    $username = $_POST['user_name'];// user name
    $useremail = $_POST['user_email'];

    $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
    $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
    $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];

    if(empty($username)){

        $errMSG = "Please Enter your full name.";
    } else if(empty($imgFile)){
                       $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
                    } else {
                        $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory
                        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
                        // valid image extensions
                        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
                        // rename uploading image
                        $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
                        // allow valid image file formats
                        if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){
                            // Check file size '5MB'
                            if($imgSize < 5000000)                {
                                move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);} } }
                    // if no error occured, continue ....
                    if(!isset($errMSG)) {
                        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName, userEmail, userPic) VALUES(:uname,  :uemail, :upic)');
                        $stmt->bindParam(':uname',$username);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':uemail',$useremail);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);

                        if($stmt->execute()) {
                            $successMSG = "Submitted successfully, thank you!";
                            header("refresh:1;futureprofile.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
                        }else {
                            $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contact" class="form-horizontal">
   
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_name"  placeholder="Your Name" required="" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" >
   
      <input class="form-control"type="text" name="user_email"  placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" required=""  value="<?php echo $useremail; ?>">
   <label>upload your future profile image</label>
<input type="file" multiple class="choose" name="user_image" placeholder="upload" value="upload" accept="image/*" >
    <button name="btnsave" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
```

index.php

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT userID, userName, userEmail, userPic FROM tbl_users WHERE userID = memberID');
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
```

output html should display user info on index.php

```
  <div class="future-name"><?php echo $userName ?> </div>
    <div class="future-email"><?php echo $userEmail ?> </div>
<img src="user_images/<?php echo $userPic ?>"/>
```

Comment: @ChrisLokhart, which column from `members` table matches with `userId` field of tbl_users?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I edited the question

Comment: @JitendraYadav "memberID" from members and "userID" from tbl_users

Comment: are you getting this information in PHP and not able to print, is that so?

Comment: @JitendraYadav It will print if i erase the WHERE clause

Comment: `memberID` from where you are getting this value in your query?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. members table is for login so memberID is the primary key. tbl_users is for a form, so userID is where I'm getting the value from.